# Error code trying to load student grade menu for individual's and all students

Tags: python, menu, pickle

Hello everyone so I am creating a student grade menu that I would like to enter a students name and two quiz grades using pickle. Once those grades are entered I would like to create a report and after I am trying to search for an individual student for my menu option two and show all students with menu option three but I get an error code every time when I am trying to print it.

```
import pickle

def menu():
  selection = input("0\tExit"
                  "\n1\tEnter Student Name/Grades"
                  "\n2\tIndividual Report"
                  "\n3\tReports"
                  "\nEnter Menu Number: ")
  if selection == "0":
    systemExit()
  if selection == "1":
    studentData()
  if selection == "2":
    singleReport()
  if selection == "3":
    studentReports()

def systemExit():
  exit()

def studentData():
  name = input("Enter Student Name: ")
  quiz1 = input("Enter Quiz 1: ")
  quiz2 = input("Enter Quiz 2: ")

with open("pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p", "ab") as pFile:
    pickle.dump((name, (quiz1, quiz2)), pFile)
clearScreen()
return()

def clearScreen():
  print("\n" * 5)
  return ()

def singleReport():
  pFile = open("pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p", "rb")
  grades_dict = pickle.load(pFile)

  search = input("Enter a Name to Search: ")

  for name in grades_dict:
    if name.upper() == search.upper():
        print(name+": "+str("pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p"[name]))

def studentReports():
  pFile = pickle.load(open("pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p", "rb"))
  print(pFile)

while True:
  menu()
```

Comment: Whats the error and in which line ?

Comment: You have to add that error.

Comment: The error is basically for "def singleReport():" and "def studentReports():", but the error code I get is for the "def singleReport():" which says "tuple object has no attribute", and for the "def studentReports():" I am trying to get all students grades to show up but only one shows up @aBiologist

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 57, in <module>
    menu()
  File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 21, in menu
    singleReport()
  File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 49, in singleReport
    if name.upper() == search.upper():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'
@hasanghaforian

Comment: can you please tell me what is content of the name from for name in grades_dict?

Comment: for name in grades_dict is the pickle file "pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p" but that for name in grades_dict is basically saying when the script finds the name in the pickle file to print the name + grade. I'm still new to programming... sorry @aBiologist

Answer (score 0):

I am basing my answer only with the error I have being given which reads as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 57, in <module> menu() File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 21, in menu singleReport() File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Fundamentals of Programming/StuGrades HW.py", line 49, in singleReport if name.upper() == search.upper(): AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

The error stating that name is a tuple which cant have the method upper and only string allow this method. So I would suggest make a simple debug using print where you can do something like:

```
for name in grades_dict:
print "name", name "and type is", type(name)
if name.upper() == search.upper():
    print(name+": "+str("pStudent_Quiz_Grades.p"[name]))
```

with this printing statement you can check what the name look like as well as the type of data name is which obviously should be a tuple. Also if we assume that search is a string variable, you can't compare string to tuple. So I would suggest just after you do the debugging is to convert the name to string so that you can allow the program to compare if the search is a string.

Comment: Okay, I will try that! Thank you @aBiologist